# I have a scheduled macro which opens/copy+pastes/save and closes another workbook, but it randomly does it more than its scheduled to do?

Tags: vba, excel

I am running a macro that opens another work book, copies and pastes, then saves and closes.

This is running each hour, but for some reason I will open my workbook after it is scheduled and there will be 3 lines copy and pasted instead of just the one?

The macro runs fine all other times apart from when you try and schedule it using application.ontime, but I can't see anything that would cause it do it more than once?

(It runs every hour but I have deleted the rest of the Application.ontimes to save space)

```
Sub AllFilesSourceTranspose()

With Application
    .Run "'G:\Research\Analysts\OK\WORKING MODELS\Barge_Tracker_V2_Hourly_Updates_SOURCE1.xlsm'!TRANSPOSEDATASOURCE"
    DoEvents
    .DisplayAlerts = False
End With

Workbooks("Barge_Tracker_V2_Hourly_Updates_SOURCE1.xlsm").Close savechanges:=True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True



 End Sub
```

---

```
Sub SchedulerForTransposeDataSOURCE1()

'-- RUNS SUB(S) (OR FUNCTIONS) AT TIME SCHEDULED.


Application.OnTime TimeValue("01:11:00"), "AllFilesSourceTranspose"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("02:11:00"), "AllFilesSourceTranspose"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("03:11:00"), "AllFilesSourceTranspose"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("04:11:00"), "AllFilesSourceTranspose"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("05:11:00"), "AllFilesSourceTranspose"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("06:11:00"), "AllFilesSourceTranspose"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("07:11:00"), "AllFilesSourceTranspose"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("08:11:00"), "AllFilesSourceTranspose"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("09:11:00"), "AllFilesSourceTranspose"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("10:11:00"), "AllFilesSourceTranspose"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("11:11:00"), "AllFilesSourceTranspose"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("12:11:00"), "AllFilesSourceTranspose"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("13:11:00"), "AllFilesSourceTranspose"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("14:11:00"), "AllFilesSourceTranspose"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("15:11:00"), "AllFilesSourceTranspose"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("16:11:00"), "AllFilesSourceTranspose"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("17:11:00"), "AllFilesSourceTranspose"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("18:11:00"), "AllFilesSourceTranspose"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("19:11:00"), "AllFilesSourceTranspose"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("20:11:00"), "AllFilesSourceTranspose"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("21:11:00"), "AllFilesSourceTranspose"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("22:11:00"), "AllFilesSourceTranspose"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("23:11:00"), "AllFilesSourceTranspose"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("23:11:00"), "AllFilesSourceTranspose"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("00:11:00"), "AllFilesSourceTranspose"

End Sub
```

Comment: I think that more information is needed. You need to make sure that `OnTime` is called only once. If `OnTime` is called many times, even with the same scheduled time and the same target macro, the macro will be invoked as many times.

Comment: @A.S.H Hi thanks for your reply, I have edited the post to show what the scheduler actually looks like. Maybe I have made a novice mistake

Comment: Ah, I see. Obviously it is better to reorganize the code so that the macro `AllFilesSourceTranspose` *reschedules itself* for the next hour. Make it so you call it only once from other code, and then it takes care of rescheduling itself. There may be other ways, but that's how I would do it.